# error: reference to ‘int64’ is ambiguous Compiling problem opencv + dlib in QT

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, g++, dlib

I have strange situation here:

I am a working code base in Mac Os X Qt. I tried to compile on ubuntu same code with same libraries (opencv + dlib ) it give a buch of errors ?

drove me crazy all day :(  any solution?

```
/usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp:314:17: error: reference to ‘int64’ is ambiguous
         virtual int64 getFLOPS(const std::vector<MatShape> &inputs,
                 ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:91:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:52,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp:46,
                 from ../SFT-V2/worker.h:18,
                 from ../SFT-V2/widget.h:5,
                 from ../SFT-V2/main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h:61:20: note: candidates are: typedef int64_t int64
    typedef int64_t int64;

    typedef int64_t int64;
```

Comment: You need to find who else defines `int64` type. According to the compiler, there are more than one definition. Probably reordering include statements might help.

Comment: missing include guard in "/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h"?

Answer (score 3):

Most probably your definition of `int64` is clashing with another definition of this type.

Sometimes in ubuntu, the compiler does not allow you to typedef the same thing twice even if the C++ standard allows you.

Reordering includes should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I removed first :

using namespace dlib from the cpp  file which is alreayd its header  not the error is gone.

But why its working on mac (clang) and not working on ubuntu (g++) ? drove me vrazy all the day to find the solution.

Comment: Could you explain better? I am unable to solve it in win11